# Select and copy to clipboard a specific item on a website with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

What is the JavaScript code to select a specific item on a website and copy it to clipboard?

Here is the code, in this case, I would like to select "Happy New Year", the item changes however so I don't really know how to reference it.

```
<div class="slds-page-header__title slds-m-right--small slds-align-middle fade-text" data-aura-rendered-by="1302:0" title="Happy New Year"><span data-aura-rendered-by="1108:0" class="uiOutputText" data-aura-class="uiOutputText">Happy New Year</span></div>
<span data-aura-rendered-by="1108:0" class="uiOutputText" data-aura-class="uiOutputText">Happy New Year</span>
```

Comment: Create a <textarea> element to be appended to the document. Set its value. ...
Append said <textarea> element to the current HTML document.
Use HTMLInputElement.select() to select the contents of the <textarea> element.
Use Document.execCommand('copy') to copy the contents of the <textarea> ...
Remove the <textarea>

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)

Answer (score -1):

You can try to use [document.execCommand('copy')](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand).

However, quoting from this [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Interact_with_the_clipboard)

> The document.execCommand() method's "cut" and "copy" commands can be
>   used to replace the clipboard's current contents with the selected
>   material. These commands can be used without any special permission if
>   you are using them in a short-lived event handler for a user action
>   (for example, a click handler).

So, one way you can achieve this by getting user's consent to copy to its clipboard by letting it to interact with your DOM.

Code sample (Credit to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46215202/1627271))

```js
function copy(text) {
  var input = document.createElement('input');
  input.setAttribute('value', text);
  document.body.appendChild(input);
  input.select();
  var result = document.execCommand('copy');
  document.body.removeChild(input);
  return result;
};

function copyText () {
  let text = document.querySelector('.uiOutputText').textContent;
  // alert(copy(text) ? 'Copied' : 'Failed to copy');
  copy(text);
}
```

```html
<div class="slds-page-header__title slds-m-right--small slds-align-middle fade-text" data-aura-rendered-by="1302:0" title="Happy New Year">
<span data-aura-rendered-by="1108:0" class="uiOutputText" data-aura-class="uiOutputText">Happy New Year</span>
</div>
<br/>
<button type="button" onclick="copyText()"> Copy </button>
```